# Rewrite potensity equation: $\frac{(\tau \cdot a)^x\cdot(\tau\cdot(b-a))^{y-x}}{(\tau \cdot b)^y}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck since yesterday on following equation
$\frac{(\tau \cdot a)^x\cdot(\tau\cdot(b-a))^{y-x}}{(\tau \cdot b)^y}$

It should be rewritten to: $(\frac{a}{b})^x \cdot (1-\frac{a}{b})^{y-x}$

I tried multiplying out everything and summarize it several times, but I don't get it right.

Does anybody has another idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may simplify by $\tau$ troughout writing
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(\tau \cdot a)^x\cdot(\tau\cdot(b-a))^{y-x}}{(\tau \cdot b)^y}&=(\tau \cdot a)^x \cdot\frac{(\tau\cdot(b-a))^{y-x}}{(\tau \cdot b)^y}
\\\\&=\frac{(\tau \cdot a)^x}{(\tau \cdot b)^x}\cdot\frac{(\tau\cdot(b-a))^{y-x}}{(\tau \cdot b)^{y-x}}
\\\\&=\frac{(a)^x}{( b)^x}\cdot\frac{(b-a)^{y-x}}{(b)^{y-x}}
\\\\&=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^x\cdot\left(\frac{b-a}{b}\right)^{y-x}
\\\\&=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^x\cdot\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)^{y-x}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thanks a lot! seems so easy, when you have it in front of you....*sigh :D

Comment: @gwendolinese You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\frac{(\tau  a)^x(\tau(b-a))^{y-x}}{(\tau b)^y}=\frac{\tau^x  a^x \tau^{y-x}(b-a)^{y-x}}{\tau^y b^y}=\frac{\tau^{x+y-x}  a^x (b-a)^{y-x}}{\tau^y b^y}=\frac{ a^x (b-a)^{y-x}}{ b^y}$$ Introduce $a=\lambda b$ to get $$A=\frac{ \lambda^x b^x (b-\lambda b)^{y-x}}{ b^y}=\frac{ \lambda^x b^x b^{y-x}(1-\lambda )^{y-x}}{ b^y}=\lambda^x (1-\lambda )^{y-x}$$ Reset $\lambda=\frac ab$.

Comment: thanks for the substitution inspiration! :)

Comment: @gwendolinese. You are very welcome !